# Not able to modify shared folders from windows 10 to ubuntu 18.04

Tags: virtualbox

```
Unexpected error: Error renaming temporary file: Text file busy
```

why this error is coming for shared folders in ubuntu installed in virtual box and the host machine is windows 10. Plz tell the remedy and don't escape by saying it is a bug plz plz.

Comment: Which temporary file did you want to rename?

Comment: I am editing a file which is in the D:\ drive of host OS i.e WINDOWS from the guest  OS ubuntu in my virtualbox via shared folders facility and I have given the write permissions to the shared folders but still not able to modify the files of host OS.

Comment: Is this a special file? How does Ubuntu know that it is a temporary file? Is it perhaps currently in use by Windows?

Comment: no it is not any special file it is just a shared file between windows and ubuntu in the virtualbox. And it is not open in the windows though also this error is showing plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using gedit ?
i found the same problem with gedit. Its a problem with gedit.
I installed some other editor, and now im able to edit and save the files without any error.

Please let me know if it helps :) :)
All the best :)

Comment: please tell me which editor you installed. Thank you very MUCH in advance. :)